WebClient blocking call - configuring a timeout
I am using Spring Boot WebClient (SB 3, Java17) in a blocking way
webClient.method(httpMethod)
         .requestUriSpec.uri(url)
         .retrieve()
         .bodyToMono(String.class)
         .block(Duration.ofSeconds(TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS));


I've read about configuring various aspects, such as response/connection/read/write timeouts, on the underlying HTTP client.
But it seems an overkill in my case as all I want is to prevent the request from blocking forever in case there is no response after X seconds. It doesn't really matter to me if the root cause was in connection timeout or response timeout.
Am I missing or over-simplifying something?
One of the reasons I am asking is because occasionally I see a timeout on block in the log but on the side that receives the request I am not able to identify a request that took long time processing.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 3000000000 NANOSECONDS
at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:127)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1738)


As usual ,we build webclient  like this ;


@Bean
public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
    return builder
            .baseUrl("http://example.com") // Your base URL
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()
                    .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000) // Connection timeout
                    .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5)) // Response timeout
            ))
            .build();
}

and you can enable debug log model, see what your got ;
logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client=DEBUG

